# Add item to a new sheet using Ui menu and trigger onChange() is not working in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Case:
I have a case using Ui Menu (onOpen()) to add data to a new sheet when the user clicks it. After that, I want to move the data from the new sheet to another spreadsheet and I'm using onChange() trigger to move the data. The trigger will work when new data is inserted on the New Sheet, but it's not working by not reading any changes that happen on the new sheet.

The Code:
I'm using the onChange(e) to move the newly inserted data on the New Sheet into another spreadsheet. I try to check and get only the active sheet and active column but the onChange(e) trigger is not working to detect when new data is added by Ui Menu to the New Sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu("Move")
    .addItem("Move to new sheet", "MovingData")
    .addToUi();
}

function onChange(e) {
  var ActiveSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var ActiveColumn = e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  console.log(ActiveSheet);
  console.log(ActiveColumn);
  if (ActiveSheet == "New Sheet" && ActiveColumn == 1) {
    //Moving data to another spreadsheet
  }
}  

function MovingData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var sheet_new = ss.getSheetByName("New Sheet");

  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      arr.push(data[i]);
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue("Done")
    
  }
  if (arr != "") {
    var newsheet_lr = sheet_new.getLastRow();
    sheet_new.getRange(newsheet_lr + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  } 
}
```

**The flow of the process:**
[image: Flow of the process]

Comment: About the script of `but the trigger is not working when new data is added by Ui Menu to the new sheet.` (Is that `MovingData`?), in your situation, how about calling the function `onChange` from this script? But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, if I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize for this.

Comment: `onChange()` is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Did you install it?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. So there are 2 sheets (1 source sheet and 1 new sheet), I move the data from the source sheet to the new sheet using MovingData(). MovingData() is to move data to the new sheet. The trigger that I mean is onChange(). The onChange() is used to track the changes that happen in the new sheet., but it can't read any changes that happen in the new sheet after new data is inserted. @Tanaike

Comment: @Tedinoz I've already installed it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Tanaike also MovingData() will run after the user click on the Ui Menu

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the new sheet name is `New Sheet` and your `onChange` is installed as an OnChange trigger, I think that when the column "A" of "New Sheet" is edited, the script in the if statement is run. How about this? By the way, in your situation, OnChange trigger is required to be used? For example, how about OnEdit trigger? And, can you provide the script of `MovingData()`? I cannot still see the whole image of your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. See [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). I'd suggest renaming your onChange function and call it altogether with the MovingData function

Comment: @Tanaike I've just added the script of MovingData()

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but the trigger is not working when new data is added by Ui Menu to the new sheet.`, as I have already mentioned in my 1st comment, how about calling the script in the if statement of the function `onChange` from the script `MovingData()`? For example, how about putting the script of `//Moving data to another spreadsheet` of `onChange` at the bottom of `MovingData`? But, if I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I very apologize for the confusion. I've just fixed my question, Thank you

Comment: So, the onChange(e) will start to run after there are changes that happen in the New Sheet

Comment: `I think that when the column "A" of "New Sheet" is edited, the script in the if statement is run. How about this?` Yeah, the onChange(e) is to detect the editing and run to move the data to another spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and updated question, I proposed 2 modification patterns. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `but the onChange(e) trigger is not working to detect when new data is added by Ui Menu to the New Sheet.`, if you want to execute `onChange` when `MovingData()` is run, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script of `onChange` is called from `MovingData`.

```js
function MovingData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var sheet_new = ss.getSheetByName("New Sheet");

  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      arr.push(data[i]);
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue("Done")
    
  }
  if (arr != "") {
    var newsheet_lr = sheet_new.getLastRow();
    sheet_new.getRange(newsheet_lr + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  } 

  // Here, copy and paste the script of "//Moving data to another spreadsheet" in "onChange" function.
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the Spreadsheet service is changed to Sheets API in "MovingData" function. When the cell is edited by Sheets API, the OnChange trigger can be fired. So, when you use this, please enable Sheets API ad Advanced Google services.

```js
function MovingData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheet_new = ss.getSheetByName("New Sheet");
  if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach(r => r[4] = "Done");
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append({ values: data }, ss.getId(), "New Sheet", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried pattern 2 and the onChange(e) could read the changes. Would you like to explain the reason why the onChange(e) could only read the changes that happen or are generated by Sheets Advanced API?

Comment: @Asking Bob Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I've just tried pattern 2 and the onChange(e) could read the changes. Would you like to explain the reason why the onChange(e) could only read the changes that happen or are generated by Sheets Advanced API?`, I couldn't understand your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because I'm worried that my understanding of your question was correct.

Comment: @Asking Bob About `Would you like to explain the reason why the onChange(e) could only read the changes that happen or are generated by Sheets Advanced API?`, I have never seen the detail of this specification in the official document. For example, the OnChange trigger is not fired with `SpreadsheetApp.openById` while it is fired with the Sheets API. So, I think that this is due to the current specification of the OnChange trigger. And, actually, this can be used. I apologize for this.